# How to use a variable name of reserved words in Python

Tags: python, peewee

I've encountered a problem when I'm using peewee in python to fetch a column's data named 'class'. But 'class' is a reserved word, when I run the code it always stopped with 'SyntaxError: invalid syntax'.

Here is the code I'm using which works if I do not include the Class.class column.

```py
query = (
    Student.select(
        Student.id,
        Student.name,
        Student.school_id,
        School.name,
        Student.class_id,
        Class.class,
        Class.grade,
    )
    .join(Class, join_type=pw.JOIN.INNER, on=(Class.id == Student.class_id))
    .join(School, join_type=pw.JOIN.INNER, on=(School.id == Student.school_id))
    .where(Student.id == id)
)
```

And the definition of Class.class which also causes the same error:

```
class = CharField(max_length=45)
```

It should give me a query without error. So my question is how do I use the variables of reserved name in python. Thanks!

Comment: Can you just rename your own field?

Comment: @Sayse Let's assume OP has an external database they just need to access using Peewee. :)

Comment: @AKX - I don't think thats a fair assumption because the obvious answer is don't name your variables the same name as reserved words

Comment: @Sayse AKX is right. We need to access the external database and we cannot edit the structure or data in that database. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, you can use `getattr` to access names that are reserved keywords; for the `class` attribute:

```py
query = (
    Student.select(
        Student.id,
        Student.name,
        Student.school_id,
        School.name,
        Student.class_id,
        getattr(Class, 'class'),  # equivalent to `Class.class` (if that were allowed)
        Class.grade,
    )
    .join(Class, join_type=pw.JOIN.INNER, on=(Class.id == Student.class_id))
    .join(School, join_type=pw.JOIN.INNER, on=(School.id == Student.school_id))
    .where(Student.id == id)
)
```

However, you probably want to rename the attribute in your Peewee table definition to something that's not a reserved word and use [`column_name='class'`](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/models.html#field-naming-conflicts) to have it still refer to a `class` attribute in the physical table:

```py
klass = CharField(max_length=45, column_name='class')
# or maybe, if you prefer:
class_ = CharField(max_length=45, column_name='class')
```

Answer (score 1):

You should name the class attribute `class_` (or something non reserved) and then use the [`column_name`](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/api.html#Field) parameter for a Peewee field to set it to "class."

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to use a reserved word in this way but it is common to add an underscore to avoid a clash such as class_ so your code would use Class.class_ or even Class_.class_